# why does expensive goes before professional?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adjective-phrases, adjective-order, participial-adjectives

It's an expensive professional camera.
In the above sentence, expensive and professional are opinion adjectives. So, why does expensive go before professional?
Thank you!

Comment: _Professional camera_ indicates the type of camera it is (the sort a professional photographer has). _Expensive_ is just an additional adjective.

Comment: ok. Thank you. I got it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The order of adjectives: Is it exactly the same in GB, the USA, and elsewhere in the English-speaking world?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98052/the-order-of-adjectives-is-it-exactly-the-same-in-gb-the-usa-and-elsewhere-in)

Answer (score 3):

'Expensive' is an *opinion*. What is expensive to one person is not necessarily to another. It is related to perceived value.

Adjectives of opinion always go first. A popular guide to order of adjectives (represented by the mnemonic *OpSAShCOMP*) suggests:

```
Opinion: pretty, horrible, lovely
Size: huge, tiny, big, little
Age: old, young, new
Shape: round, square, triangular
Colour: black, red, yellow
Origin: British, Chinese, French
Material: woollen, wooden, silk
Purpose: writing (paper), school (shoes)
```

So, for example, you might have an *expensive new Japanese camera*.

Comment: So, what about professional? what kind of adjectives does professional belong to?

Comment: @HồDuyLợi I would say it describes the camera's *purpose*: This camera is intended for professional use.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you very much!